# What message does David's fingerprint carry?

Tags: character, prometheus

In *Prometheus*, David's fingerprint looks like this:

[image: original fingertip image]

David's fingerprint does look very different from humans. I am wondering what kind of message his finger print carry?

Has it been mentioned anywhere in the Alien universe?

Here is an annotated and gamma-adjusted version to make it clearer:

[image: Can actually see the fingerprint]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In first glimpse it looks like Weyland Corp logo to me. And I am not alone in that thought.

> If one looks closely when David examines a drop of the Black Liquid on his fingertip, it can be seen that a few of his fingerprint's friction ridges form the Weyland Corp logo. This can also been seen in David's introduction video. [- avp.wikia.com](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/David_(USCSS_Prometheus))

And from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/trivia?item=tr1714529):

> The three-triangle logo of the Weyland corporation (while visually similar to that of the actual Weinstein Group) is actually derived from a pattern appearing on the wall in the background of an early Ron Cobb production painting of the "Space Jockey" for the original Alien (1979) film. The logo can be seen as part of David's fingerprint.

Comment: property of ...